# Распределить данные пользователей по категориям

Tags: javascript

Есть массив с категориями ролей `userByRoles` и массив пользователей с ролями `users`. Как лучше распихать пользователей с `users` в `userByRoles.children`. Мой способ по моему мнению очень не красивый и не читабельный, хотелось его бы как-то отрефакторить.

P.S. в `userByRoles` можно изменять любые данные кроме `title & children`

```js
let userByRoles = [{
    title: 'Role 1',
    value: '0',
    key: 'role_1',
    children: []
  },
  {
    title: 'Role 2',
    value: '1',
    key: 'role_2',
    children: []
  },
  {
    title: 'Role 3',
    value: '2',
    key: 'role_3',
    children: []
  },
  {
    title: 'All users',
    value: '3',
    key: 'all_users',
    children: []
  }
];

const users = [{
  name: 'user 1',
  role: 'role_1'
}, {
  name: 'user 2',
  role: 'role_1'
}, {
  name: 'user 3',
  role: 'role_2'
}, {
  name: 'user 4',
  role: 'role_2'
}, {
  name: 'user 5',
  role: 'role_3'
}, {
  name: 'user 6',
  role: 'role_4'
}, {
  name: 'user 7',
  role: 'role_5'
}, {
  name: 'user 9',
  role: 'role_4'
}, {
  name: 'user 10',
  role: 'role_3'
}, {
  name: 'user 11',
  role: 'role_2'
}, ]

function myFunc() {
  users.forEach((value) => {
    if (value.role === 'role_1') {
      userByRoles[0].children.push({
        name: value.name
      })
    } else if (value.role === 'role_2') {
      userByRoles[1].children.push({
        name: value.name
      })
    } else if (value.role === 'role_3') {
      userByRoles[2].children.push({
        name: value.name
      })
    } else {
      userByRoles[3].children.push({
        name: value.name
      })
    }
  });
  return userByRoles;
}

console.log(myFunc())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать так.

```js
let userByRoles = [{
    title: 'Role 1',
    value: '0',
    key: 'role_1',
    children: []
  },
  {
    title: 'Role 2',
    value: '1',
    key: 'role_2',
    children: []
  },
  {
    title: 'Role 3',
    value: '2',
    key: 'role_3',
    children: []
  },
  {
    title: 'All users',
    value: '3',
    key: 'all_users',
    children: []
  }
];

const users = [{
  name: 'user 1',
  role: 'role_1'
}, {
  name: 'user 2',
  role: 'role_1'
}, {
  name: 'user 3',
  role: 'role_2'
}, {
  name: 'user 4',
  role: 'role_2'
}, {
  name: 'user 5',
  role: 'role_3'
}, {
  name: 'user 6',
  role: 'role_4'
}, {
  name: 'user 7',
  role: 'role_5'
}, {
  name: 'user 9',
  role: 'role_4'
}, {
  name: 'user 10',
  role: 'role_3'
}, {
  name: 'user 11',
  role: 'role_2'
}, ]


function myFunc2() {
  const roleHash = {};
  const allUserRole = userByRoles.find(f => f.key === 'all_users');
  roleHash['all_users'] = allUserRole;
  users.forEach((user) => {
    let role = roleHash[user.role] || userByRoles.find(f => f.key === user.role) || allUserRole;
    if (!roleHash[user.role])
      roleHash[user.role] = role;
    role.children.push(user);
  });
  return userByRoles;
}

console.log(myFunc2())
```

Comment: Почему то нету никакого результата при выполнение кода.

Comment: @Puvvl Потому что я отключил в сниппете показ консоли. Откройте консоль и наслаждайтесь.

Comment: Не знал что так можно, спасибо :)